# Determinstic finite automata language

Tags: regex, dfa

If I can derive a regex that satisfies some of the DFA and terminates, how would I represent the language?

For example, terminal state `S` goes to state `X`, which gives a regex, but when going from `S` to state `Z`, never terminates.

```
L = {...}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Furthermore a DFA always terminates since there is guaranteed progress...

Comment: A regex *is* a DFA.